# JQuery datatable column data update works too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, execution-time

Working on generating table using datatable.
I have textbox below the table, when I add any value to that textbox then that value should be updated to specific column of 1st row then each row should be increment by 1 for that column(new updated value).

I have code for that, that works fine for me. But it takes too much time for that. I have 159 records in table and when I update column then it takes about to 8-9 seconds, this is very long duration. Till execution complete I am not able to do anything.

JS code:

```
updateNo: function(dataTableId, noColIndex, numToAdd) {
    var dataTable = $(dataTableId).dataTable();
    var numberOfRows = dataTable.api().rows().data().length;
    var index;
    for (index = 0; index < numberOfRows; index++) {
        var cell = dataTable.api().cell(index, noColIndex);
        var currentNo = cell.data();
        var newNo = parseInt(currentNo) + numToAdd;
        cell.data(newNo).draw();
    }
}
```

I have tried to calculate method execution time and found that last line of method: `cell.data(newNo).draw();` takes more time to execute.

I am not so much proficient in JavaScript or Jquery so I don't know the reason. If someone knows the reason and fix for this issue then please let me know.

I want to decrease execution time for this.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://debug.datatables.net/) can be of assistance to you.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to redraw every cell, just redraw the entire table once after executing your code

Comment: sorry, can you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: okay found the fix from your hint, works too fast now. `dataTable.fnDraw()`

Comment: i think fnDraw is the old name, are you using an older version of DataTables? dataTable.draw() should do the job

Comment: Yes its old version, as our system is older. :)